# Keyof interface Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function here in Typescript:

```
const updateItem = (key: keyof IDevice, val: string | number, i: number) => {
    const devices = [...formData.devices];

    const device = devices[i];

    // @ts-ignore
    device[key] = val;

    devices[i] = device;

    setFormData({ ...formData, devices });
};
```

IDevice:

```
export interface IDevice {
    name: string;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    userAgentString: string;
}
```

Formdata is of type:

```
interface FormState {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    devices: IDevice[];
}
```

And the error I see is this:

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Please help me out as I'm not a pro with Typescript.

Comment: What's the type of your `formData.devices`? I assume it should be `IDevice`, but it might be it isn't for some reason. Also I assume the error happens where you added the `@ts-ignore`?

Comment: Please share runnable code? what is `formData,IDevice` ?

Comment: are you using typescript with react ?

Comment: @GouthamJ.M Yes.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs Yeah the error is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change your function definition to make it work:

```js
function updateItem<K extends keyof IDevice>(key: K, val: IDevice[K], i: number) {
    const devices = [...formData.devices];

    const device = devices[i];

    device[key] = val;

    devices[i] = device;

    setFormData({ ...formData, devices });
}
```

By extracting the key type and making it generic, TypeScript plays much more nicely. It also has the advantage that e.g. `updateItem('height', 'string', 0)` will produce a TS error because it expects a `number` for the `height` field.

*[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBEIDdhOQbwFgAoZM5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4TzkB3YAEzAALeiACuVAEbROpckIjBWQsKInSos7mIbQAgqwjgAyszb0mLEBxIBfEiVCRYiFADEA9lCqm4kAlzklDQWZtZa5PwQDAgsAA5gwB4goVY2cmRROEgM9BjYuBAA2gC6svbEJAD0VcgAAmAMALRKIF4ocAwMEigQAB7OlAA2yFhwLHCSQxAkCMlMyDBeVOh%20cPSe3r6QsnMgC7pgmytr9HAgAJ7IALwUYkNDsiQwYiAIicnIYnH8fhCokCoAB4ANLIfqQED8BjIADWEAuHhgaEw2QgAD4ABTwi70EEAGlGcCGeVRhSKIJKhOAaik0AAlAEMsg9gssoUYbcigA6XmY8QPACEyE6yGO2wg9O57JyZQczNZYGQMpQtxVDCKwDllWZKqKOJKNyJj3l3HVmsNaoKSCezMOx1WYDgmPwyF53KW3kdcEJ6uQtnp5SAA)*

Comment: Thanks Man, works like a charm! Also, how would you recommend learning advanced typescript?

Comment: @Akash Besides reading the TS handbook and tutorials? Honestly just practice, try things out, ... I've learnt the above from also struggling to create that kind of function. Over time you'll get a feel for certain things, e.g. having the `K` type be a generic parameter.